# How to find probability transition matrix for continuous time markov chain?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

In Grimmet and Stirzaker, on page 258 it explains how to find transition probabilities, given a generator matrix:

> (a) nothing happens during $(t,t+h)$ with probability $1+g_{ii}*h+o(h)$
>
> (b) the chain jumps to state $j(\ne i)$ with probability
>   $g_{ij}*h+o(h)$

Clearly the above is a function of the incremental time into the future, $h$.  Then, observing equation (8) a little bit below on the same page 258, we can see that by taking the limit as h goes to 0 of $\frac{1}{h}(P_h – I)=G$.  That makes sense for the above (a) and (b).

Now look at the example (15) on page 260:
The generator matrix is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    -\alpha & \alpha \\
    \beta & -\beta
\end{bmatrix}
$$

And, solving for the transition probabilities (as shown on Page 267 and 268) we get the following:
$$P_t=
\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\beta+\alpha*e^{-(\alpha+\beta)*t}}{\beta+\alpha} & \frac{\alpha-\alpha*e^{-(\alpha+\beta)*t}}{\beta+\alpha} \\
    \frac{\beta-\beta*e^{-(\alpha+\beta)*t}}{\beta+\alpha} & \frac{\alpha+\beta*e^{-(\alpha+\beta)*t}}{\beta+\alpha} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
using (a) and (b) on page 258, I would understand the transition probabilities to be

$p_{00}=1+g_{ii}*h+o(h) = 1-\alpha *h+o(h)$

$p_{01}=g_{ij}*h+o(h) = \beta*h+o(h)$

$p_{11}=1+g_{ii}*h+o(h) = 1-\beta *h+o(h)$

$p_{10}=g_{ij}*h+o(h) = \alpha*h+o(h)$

Which set of transition probabilities is correct?

Comment: Indexing the states by $\{0,1\}$, one finds $$1+g_{00}h+o(h) = 1-\alpha h+o(h)\quad g_{01}h+o(h) = \alpha h+o(h)$$ and $$ 1+g_{11}h+o(h) = 1-\beta h+o(h)\quad g_{10}h+o(h) = \beta h+o(h)$$ **exactly as desired**. What is your question?

Comment: Thanks, @Did.  I see that is one way to get the transition probabilities from having knowledge of the matrix $G$.  But, on page 267 and 268 the transition probability matrix is shown to have entries as I showed in the matrix $P_t$.  This is different.  e.g. $1+g_{00}+o(h) \ne \frac{\beta+\alpha*e^{-(\alpha+\beta)*t}}{\beta+\alpha}$.  These are only the same when $h=0$ and $t=0$, but why are they different at all?

Comment: Wait, would you be confusing the matrix $P_t$ for a fixed positive $t$, with the expansion up to order $t$ of its entries when $t\to0$?

Comment: Thanks @Did! I did not notice that.  Now, I'm not understanding when to use one over the other.  If I know the matrix $G$, then it seems like I can always obtain $P_t$ using $1+g(i,i)*h+O(h)$ and $g(i,j)*h+O(h)$?  So, then for example why would I ever need to solve the Kolmogorov Forward Equations when I can get $P_t$ must more simply?

Comment: Actually, $G=\lim\limits_{t\to0}(P_t-I)/t$ and $P_t=e^{tG}$.

Comment: Yes but then if you do a first order approximation, you will always obtain $1-g(i,i)*h+O(h)$ and $g(i,j)*h+O(h)$.   I suppose you are saying that this first order approximation is only done when finding G because we are taking the limit as t goes to 0?

Comment: Yes one will obtain this expansion when $t\to0$ (but why "but"?). With $1+g(i,i)h+o(h)$ rather than $1-g(i,i)h+o(h)$, though. No idea what you are saying that I am saying, in the last sentence of your comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86851/discussion-between-candic3-and-did).

Comment: "but" is used because it seems to me like the $P=e^{tG}$ is never necessary if we only care about first order. and in most applications (birth death, branching etc., we only care about first order approximation)usually (according to Grimmet and Stirzaker and other sources), we care about determining the possible events according to "one jump" in a stochastic process, so the linearized first order approximation is almost always enough. So, I'm wondering if I see a G matrix, can I just immediately get P_t matrix by this linearization and work with that instead?

Comment: "But" the linearization will not get you $P_t$ since $P_t\ne I+tG$ for $t>0$ fixed. And yes there are situations where $P_t$ itself is interesting, not only its asymptotics when $t\to0^+$, for example, in the whole field of heat kernels estimates.

Comment: okay, getting closer,  thank you. So then, my next question is when are we assuming this first order approximation?  E.g. is the Kolmogorov forward equation assuming this first order approximation when it shows $\frac{d P_t}{dt}=P_t*G$?  Similarly for Chapman-Kolmogorov I cannot tell if it is using a first order approximation to say $\mu_{t+s}=\mu_t*P_s$.

Comment: Sorry but you are trying to extract from me, bit by bit, the contents of the first chapter of any textbook on the subject. The site is not designed for such tasks. Get a textbook and study it.